# css file is not loading on localhost using xampp

Tags: html, css, xampp, localhost

I'm trying to include css and js files in my php files on localhost:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/neu/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/neu/css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/neu/scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/neu/scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/neu/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I'm using xampp with this structure:

css-files:

[image]

php-files:

[image]

On the source view of the site I can click on the links for the .css and .js files and the correct files are shown.

I also tried `href="neu/css/...` but the same, the .css and .js are not loading on my page.
Also tried loading the .css from outside (like `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`) but the same.

So it is possible that xampp is blocking somehow the links? Thanks

**Edit:**

Screenshot from Developer Tools:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you see any error in browser console?

Comment: Is your PHP that you are trying to add those css and js files in neu folder ?

Comment: @zihad no I see no errors

Comment: @Aldin yes I use a php helper file to include the html head

Comment: I've removed the PHP tag as there is no PHP code in this question, only HTML (and perhaps CSS and JS linked/referenced). What is your understanding of linking files in HTML (page) context?

Comment: _"So it is possible that xampp is blocking somehow the links?"_ - Yes, possible, but _very_ likely **no**. XAMPP, and therefore Apache (the "A" in "XAMPP") is on duty to _server_ files, that is what it is for. Most likely this is a logical issue in getting HTML on the server to work. Easier can be to work with static HTML files first and the use of _relative_ links.

Comment: @hakre sry I don't unterstand what you mean - What is your understanding of linking files in HTML (page) context?

Comment: What do you know about linking files in HTML pages? What is your understanding of the HTML code/segment you posted?

Comment: Hmm Can you show me your head from browser developer tools, does your links show there ? Probably you didn't linked them properly, if your PHP head layout is  there in neu folder you should go ./css/yourfile.css

Comment: @Aldin pls see my edit

Comment: Open the Network tab in the browser's developer tools. Look for the requests for the resources. See if the status code, content-type header, and content are what you expect.

Comment: @Quentin pls see my edit with the screenshot

Comment: @Kᴀτᴢ — That shows the status code. What about the content-type and the content?

Comment: @Quentin I added another screenshot, hope this is the right one

Answer (score -1):

If your root folder is neu then I dont think its necessary to add hat in the address. try using ....href="css/... Also I sometimes experience no change in style when I add css until I clear cache.... I think in your case is the address and then try clearing cache

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: remove htt://localhost/localhost/neu from the links and it should work